There are $n$ positive integers $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$. For any distinct $a,b,c,d$, $x_a+x_b≠x_c+x_d$​. What is the minimum possible value of $x_n$​?
Is there a closed-form solution for the minimum value of $x_n$? Alternatively, what is its asymptotic behavior?
The first few values of minimum of $x_n$​ are:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
n&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
{\rm min}\ x_n&5&8&13&19&25\\\hline
\end{array}$$
My totally unoptimized code fails to find a solution for $n=9$ after running for an entire day. Are there known techniques or algorithms to compute or estimate these values more efficiently?

Indeed:  given a good list for $n-1$, the maximal sum you can get out of it is $x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$, so taking that value always gives you a "good" list (though presumably not a minimal one).  Thus we get a "Fibonacci" style upper bound, which in this case shows that the answer for $n=9$ is no greater than $44$.

There are some initial values provided in this post. This does take a lot of work to nail down the exact minimum.

One big problem is that the minimal list for $n$ need not be an extension of a minimal list for $n-1$.

See also https://oeis.org/A039836 (referred to in the post from user @Calvin).

Looking at the results in the post from @Calvin, it seems that min $x_n\propto n^\frac{5}{2}$
